# Error con un setter en javascript

Tags: javascript

hola querida comunidad como ya sabran me estoy iniciando en la programacion  y voy por la enseñanza de setters y getters, pillo los getters pero me cuesta bastante entender el setter y creo por eso tengo este error por mas que defino una segunda variable me sigue arrojando error saben por que

```javascript
    class Media {
      constructor(title) {
        this._title = title;
        this._isCheckedOut = false;
        this._ratings = ratings;
      }
      get title() {
        
        return this._title;
      }
      
      get isCheckedOut() {
          
          return this._isCheckedOut;
      }
    
      get ratings() {
    
            return this._ratings;
      }
    
      
    set isCheckedOut(newCheckedOut) {
    
      return this._isCheckedOut = newCheckedOut;
    }
    
     toggleCheckOutStatus() {
    
        this._isCheckedOut  = !this._isCheckedOut;

}
    
  
    
    const historyOfEverything = new Book('Bill Bryson', 'A Short History of Nearly Everything', 544)
    historyOfEverthing.toggleCheckOutStatus();
```

Comment: Que error tienes???

Answer (score 2):

Un error de formulacion/convencion es:

Los setters no deberían retornar nada, solo modificar el valor de la propiedad. Entonces cambia esto:

```
set isCheckedOut(newCheckedOut) {
  return this._isCheckedOut = newCheckedOut;
}
```

Por Esto:

```
set isCheckedOut(newCheckedOut) {
  this._isCheckedOut = newCheckedOut;
}
```

Aunque el principal error que cometes en tu codigo es:

```
class Media {
    constructor(title) {
    //...
    }
}

const historyOfEverything = new Book('.....')
```

Creas una classe llamada Media i la intentas llamar llamando a Book.
Una vez cambies una de las dos palabras, fijate tambien que cuando creas la instancia de la clasee le pasas 2 parametros (autor i titulo) pero la clase solo acepta uno (title).

Un saludo!